# Via Excel VBA, opening Word Document to Complete Mail-merge. Is there way to Automatically set Word Doc Source equal to Excel Spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

Have the below Excel VBA Code:

1. Creates Word Object since I want to link my spreadsheet to a Word Mailmerge template
2. Asks the user to specify the Word Template
3. Opens the Word Template (to which later code not displayed merges the data with the template)

Challenge: if the Word Template is already "sourced" to a different spreadsheet (say the spreadsheet from last month which has a different name), the user has to go through the steps to select the "newer" spreadsheet which I am calling the Word Template from.

Question: is there a way within the Excel VBA (or other) to open the word doc so that the source is changed to the current spreadsheet?

```
Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If wd Is Nothing Then
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

Dim Letter_File As FileDialog
Set Letter_File = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With Letter_File
    .Filters.Clear
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "\\Nasprod-5\gbop\Customer Service\RMDs\Process Improvements\"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        Fileaddress = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

If MsgBox(Fileaddress, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
    MsgBox ("Canceled")
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open(Fileaddress)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is code I use in Word vba.

```
Dim strFileName As String
strFileName = WorkGroupPath & "Parts\Merge Data\Clients_Merge.xlsm"
'
'   Attach Merge list
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    .OpenDataSource Name:=strFileName, _
                    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Clients$`"    ', _
                                                                '
    '       Show merge data
    .ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = False
End With

'   Find client
Application.Dialogs(wdDialogMailMergeFindRecipient).Show
```

This is run upon opening/creating the primary merge document. You could assign the long name of your data source to strFilename.

You might have to change the With to:

```
With wd.ActiveDocument.MailMerge
```

The following came from recording a MailMerge in Word.

```
    .OpenDataSource Name:=strFileName, _
                    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Clients$`"    ', _
```

Comment: My question is unclear in that what I am trying to "prevent" with Excel VBA is the following: 1) Word Template is linked to a previous Excel Spreadsheet.  2) When I open up a newer version of the Excel Spreadsheet and attempt to link to it via Excel VBA, the Word Template is looking for the previous version (which has moved) and thus requests the user to select a new spreadsheet (as though you manually linking the word doc to the spreadsheet within Word).  Looking for a way within Excel VBA to "forget" the previous spreadsheet link and accept linking from the spreadsheet from Excel VBA.

Comment: Word Template or Document? http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm You should not be *opening* the template but creating a new document ('Documents.New'). That will become the ActiveDocument.

Comment: To fix your problem, **open** your template and disconnect it from the merge (Start Mail Merge > Normal Word Document) then save it. When a new document is created, change it to a letter merge document and attach your data. The code to do this is in my sample code. Once you have completed the merge, close the new primary merge *document* without saving.

Comment: If you are dealing with a document rather than a template, same thing except you can close the existing document (which you have changed to a merge document) without saving so that it is still a normal word document.